# How to add arrays to a list and iterate to get the first values of each array?

Tags: arrays, list, arraylist, iteration

This is how the problem statement goes :

Suppose there are 4 string arrays - [open,providers] , [1,2] , [yes,no] , [oe,pr]

I want to add the 4 arrays to a List named 'series' .

So the series list is now like - [[open,providers],[1,2],[yes,no],[oe,pr]]

Now i want to iterate through the list to get the first values from each array in the list , that is get [open,1,yes,oe] and [providers,2,no,pr] as two separate arrays or lists .

How to go about this ? 
Help with code segments ! 
THANKS !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    String[] arr1 = {"open","providers"};
    String[] arr2 = {"1","2"};
    String[] arr3 = {"yes","no"};

    List<String[]> addList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    for (int n = 0; n < arr1.length; n++) {
        String[] rowArray = { arr1[n], arr2[n],
                arr3 [n]};
        addList.add(rowArray);

    }
```

This is provided , the length of the arrays are similar which can be accomodated quite easily !

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this. I tested here and it's working fine. Just improve your `println` to show your text as you like. Now it is up to you. Study the code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String[] array1 = {"open", "providers"};
        String[] array2 = {"1", "2"};
        String[] array3 = {"yes", "no"};
        String[] array4 = {"oe", "pr"};

        ArrayList<String[]> result = myArrays(array1, array2, array3, array4);

        for(int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < result.get(i).length; j++) {
                if(i == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Result of first array: " + result.get(i)[j]);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Result of second array: " + result.get(i)[j]);
                }   
            }
        }
    }


    public static ArrayList<String[]> myArrays(String[] array1, String[] array2, String[] array3, String[] array4) {

        String[][] series = new String[4][];
        series[0] = array1;
        series[1] = array2;
        series[2] = array3;
        series[3] = array4;

        String[] firstResult = new String[4];
        String[] secondResult = new String[4];

        for(int i = 0; i < series.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < series[i].length; j++) {
                if(j == 0) {
                    firstResult[i] = series[i][j];
                } else {
                    secondResult[i] = series[i][j];
                }
            }
        }

        ArrayList<String[]> finalResult = new ArrayList<String[]>();

        finalResult.add(firstResult);
        finalResult.add(secondResult);

        return finalResult;
    }
}
```

Comment: this looks great ! now what if there are more like {open,prov,...,...}{1,2,3,....} in the arrays

Comment: it works too, but you have to add more parameters. if you need three separate results, add a thirdResult. If you want 5 arrays as input, create and add a fifth one. And so on.